# Fit Baidu map to multiple markers like Google Maps fitBounds

Tags: javascript, baidu-map

Is there an equivalent in Baidu like fitBounds in GoogleMap?
I have multiple markers on a Baidu map and I would like to show all the markers with the proper positioning and zoom level.

Answer (score 10):

Just stumbling upon this thread. The answer to this question is:

```
var points = [Point_1,...,Point_n];
map.setViewport(points);
```

`points` is simply an array containing objects of type `BMap.Point` that you want within the map viewport.

Docs: http://developer.baidu.com/map/reference/index.php?title=Class:%E6%80%BB%E7%B1%BB/%E6%A0%B8%E5%BF%83%E7%B1%BB

Answer (score 1):

Although [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31798308/8262804) worked for me, with the change of direct `latlng` object instead of `BMap.Point` object to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to show multiple markers on Baidu Map.

[Check their example here](http://developer.baidu.com/map/jsdemo.htm#c1_3)

I have displayed Baidu Map with an area of 230x125 so I have shown the China on the area like below:

```
var map     = new BMap.Map("id_of_map_loading_area");
var point   = new BMap.Point(101.841797,35.433724); //China on the center of the area
map.centerAndZoom(point,3);  // Change value 3 to see difference
map.enableScrollWheelZoom(); // Zoom effect to the map using mouse.
```